# Using Ref<> for generic Eigen matrices in a templated function

Tags: c++, templates, eigen, eigen3

Here is a function I would like to write:

```
template<typename NumType> using Vec = Eigen::Matrix<NumType, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>;


template<typename T>
void foo(Eigen::Ref<Vec<T>> p)
{
  // fill p with things
}

void main()
{
  Vec<double> v(2);
  foo(v)
}
```

In particular I would like to be able to call `foo` without passing in a type parameter to the template, but instead have the function infer the type by the argument.  When I run this code I get the error that

```
No matching function call to 'foo'
Candidate template ignored: could not match 'Ref' against 'Matrix'
```

This function works fine if I pass in the type to the function call, such as `foo<double>(v)`.  I also know the type `T` can be inferred if the signature of `foo` is

```
template<typename T>
void foo(Vec<T> & p)
```

but that is not a good way of passing Eigen vectors by reference as it destroys the benefits of expression templates.

I also can not use the `MatrixBase` method of passing by reference

```
template<typename Derived>
void foo(Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& p)
```

because I want to be sure the vector being passed in is of type `T`, and I don't know how to ensure that with this method.

Is there a way of using `Ref<>` in a templated function like this where it will infer the type `T`?  All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For template code use the `MatrixBase` approach, and to control the scalar type, then use either a static assertion or a `enable_if` construct. Use `typename Derived::Scalar` to get the scalar type of the expression.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I currently have a work-around that is `template<T> void foo(MatrixBase<Vec<T>>)`, however this does not work if I pass in a vector of fixed size.  Can you explain why it can't convert a fixed sized vector to a dynamically sized vector?  I'm mostly just trying to understand how it all works, but I also like this method because it does not allow my user to pass in a matrix when I want a vector.  I can of course check to be sure the parameter is a vector, but this seems more elegant.

Comment: I think your followup comment is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74194702/non-const-reference-of-eigen-matrix-only-bind-with-dynamic-types-and-not-with-no)